# What's the standard Android way to load a large array of data on start-up for an Activity?

Tags: android, file-io, android-activity

I'm reading a JSON file containing a single object mapping string color names to string color hex codes in onCreate in my Activity and, parsing it, and saving the data as arrays in my Activity.  This color data is required to show anything meaningful in the UI, but I feel like this can't be the best way to do this.  Is there an XML resource file type or standard binary format that I should convert this data into?  Should I be doing this in onCreate or some other part of the start-up process?

The file contains about a thousand data points, and even though they don't ever vary after compile time, it seems ludicrous to hard code them into the application, so I'm assuming there's an Android standard middle ground between parsing this JSON file and hard coding it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a TypedArray in your resources (create res/values/colordata.xml  for example)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <array name="colors">
            <item>#FFFF0000</item>
            <item>#FF00FF00</item>
            <item>#FF0000FF</item>
        </array>
    </resources>
```

and then use code similar to this to retrieve the values :

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray colors = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.colors);

int count = colors.getIndexCount();
for (i=0; i< count;i++){
    int color = colors.getColor(i,0);
    // .. act on a color
}
```

see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray for more background

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'll often store data like that in json and use gson to parse it into an object.

The important thing is that you don't parse it on the main thread. Use an AsyncTask or other threading to do the work of the main thread to prevent ui glitches.

But the json parsing is not really a problem in and of itself, assuming your data set is in the hundreds to thousands range. CPU is relatively cheap.